# Create a loop to be performed up to a certain point

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have this little snippet of code

```
for (var m=number_of_days;m>number_of_days-3;m--) 
              {
               ...
              }
```

Essentially I need it to count back and loop through 3 times. However there are conditions where number_of_days =1 or 2. In which case I need the loop to execute only 1 or 2 times.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your answer  is exactly what I have typed above

Comment: `for (var m = number_of_days; m > number_of_days - 3 && m > 0; m--) { ... }`?

Answer (score 1):

Just swap your number 3 for a variable, eg called number_of_loops. Set number_of_loops based on whatever conditions you need.

```
if(condition){
     var number_of_loops = 2;
} else {
     var number_of_loops = 3;
}

for (var m = number_of_days; m > number_of_days - number_of_loops;m--){
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, actually I think I misread your question! if number of loops is always the same, you probably want this instead: `for (m = number_of_days; m > Math.max(0,number_of_days-3); m--){}` (similar to @le_m 's suggestion)